# Resistors amplifier circuit

Tags: resistors

on an amplifier I found at the input 4 resistors of 0 ohms.
What is their role and how does this circuit work?
[image]

Comment: This circuit can be used in different combinations: non inverting or inverting. By placing or leaving out those 0 Ohm resistors we can choose which configuration we want. And WHOA, we can use **one PCB design** to make either configuration. 2 circuits but one PCB. It is a common thing in many devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For a non-inverting amplifier R4 = 0 and R5 = \$\infty\$
- For a non-inverting amplifier R6 = 0 and R7 = \$\infty\$

And,

- For an inverting amplifier R5 = 0 and R4 = \$\infty\$
- For an-inverting amplifier R7 = 0 and R6 = \$\infty\$